# How can I make it so that the loop keeps repeating until a all the elements in the list are answered?

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make it so that the question or sequence keeps getting repeated until user has named every day of the week and prints a message that congratulates the user after that. I am trying to use a while loop but I can't seem to get it to work. I have also tried using an if statement although it does work, it doesn't repeat the question and keep adding to the list continously.

This is the output that I am trying to get...
[image]

```
days = []
days2 = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
answer = input('Enter a day of the week: ')

while answer in days2:
        days.append(answer)
        print('%s has been added to our days of the week.' % answer)
        print(days)

if answer in days:
    print('Sorry already in our list.')
if answer
else:
    print('Sorry %s is not a day of the week.' % answer)
```

This is what I have so far

Thank youu :D

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text itself, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code). For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: It looks like you have an errant `if answer`

Comment: Relevant: [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](/q/23294658/4518341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `if` statement is out of the loop, and your loop will immediately exit if a user enters a value, not found in `days2`. Ie. if a user enters value `monday`, `while loop` will be skipped and the program will continue executing reaching an `if` part.

On the other hand, if a user enters a value that is found in list `days2` for the first time, your program will continue running in the `while loop` until user enters something that is not in the list `days2`.

Instead of a list, you might need to consider using set object. One of the correct answers, adapting from your code would be this:

```py
days = set()
# this is also a set
days2 = {'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'}

# let's avoid a problem where a user can exit the program from the beginning
# therefore, this should be inside the loop
# answer = input('Enter a day of the week: ')

while len(days) < 7:
    answer = input('Enter a day of the week: ')
    if answer in days2 and answer in days:
        print('Sorry already in our list')
    elif answer not in days2:
        print('Sorry %s is not a day of the week.' % answer)
    else:
        days.add(answer)
        print('%s has been added to our days of the week.' % answer)
        print(days)
```

Answer (score 3):

Your current loop structure doesn't make sense.
Your validity test *does* look good!

Here is the high-level outline you want to strive for:

```
while fewer than seven elements in days:
    solicit a new day from the user
    figure out if it's valid - correct spelling and not present
    if it's a valid day:
        tack it onto the list
```

At some point, a patient user will enter all the days
and len() will return 7, allowing the `while` loop to terminate.

Comment: That should be, "if it's a valid day **and** it hasn't already been added to the list"

Comment: Yeah, I guess I tend to think of such things in terms of a `set()`, where adding a day N times is idempotent.

Answer (score 2):

There are several decent answers on here already, but I took a slightly different approach to the problem:

```
days_of_week = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']
entered_days = []

while days_of_week != []:
    answer = input('Enter a day of the week: ').casefold()
    if((answer in days_of_week) and not(answer in entered_days)):
        entered_days.append(answer)
        days_of_week.remove(answer)
        print('%s has been added to our days of the week.' % answer.capitalize())
        print(entered_days)
    elif answer in entered_days:
        print('Sorry already in our list.')
    else:
        print('Sorry %s is not a day of the week.' % answer)
print("Well done! You have populated the list.")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do this, but here is one that seems to be in the spirit of what you are going for.

```
days = []
days2 = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', 'sunday']

while sorted(days) != sorted(days2):
    answer = input('Enter a day of the week: ').lower()
    if answer in days:
        print('Sorry already in our list.')     
    elif answer not in days2:
        print('Sorry %s is not a day of the week.' % answer)
    else:        
        days.append(answer)
        print('%s has been added to our days of the week.' % answer)
        print(days)

print("you got them all!")
```

I'd suggest looking to Python flow control, using things like `next`, `for`, `while`, `break`, etc.  Note the `lower()` as well, since Python cares about case and I would guess you want `Monday` treated the same as `monday`.  Also when comparing lists it cares about the order, so I just `sorted` each one.